# Cast in lambda expression when call static methods, pass it as parameter as functional interface and use method references instead

Tags: java

In this List:

```
List<Emp> emp = Arrays.asList (
            new Emp ("John", "Smith"),
            new Emp ("Peter", "Sam"),
            new Emp ("Peter", "Ham"),
            new Emp ("Peter", "Brown"));
```

Where Emp is a bean with two String fields and setters and getters.  And the next:

```
emp.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(e->e.getfName()).thenComparing(o1->o1.getlName()));
```

The previous line doesn`t compile, it will compile if I cast the element in the implementation of the lambda like this:

```
emp.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(e->((Emp) e).getfName()).thenComparing(o1->((Emp) o1).getlName()));
```

I have to specify the type (Emp).  However, if I use method references instead, I already specify the type:

```
emp.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Emp::getfName).thenComparing(Emp::getlName));
```

I'd thank comments.

Comment: Missing the question?

Comment: You can avoid casts by using longer lambda form: `(Emp e) -> e.getfName()`. However, your question lacks the actual question in it. Are you confused by this compiler problem?

Comment: `Comparator.<Emp>comparing(...)`